# What is the effect of external ESD protection on noise?

Tags: noise, esd

I am measuring very small currents/voltages (nA, uV) using a precision op-amp. What effect on noise is likely from external ESD protection (clamping to +/- 15V) on the input signal path?

Circuit below

[image]

Comment: good noise generators

Comment: Are those really Zener clamps? Zener/avalanche diodes are amazing noise gens...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel zener noise is a big problem *if they are conducting* which they shouldn't be. I'd worry about their leakage current though.

Comment: Isn't zener capacitance largish below their threshold voltage? (I don't know if they are even tested for that parameter.) Wouldn't this have some impact on your integrators \$C_{14}\$ and \$C_{31}\$; as integrator error, poles and zeros, and kTC noise? (It must be my lack of experience, but how do you reset the accumulated charges? By de-integrating it back off? I don't see switches here.)

Comment: @jonk It's actually a current to voltage converter

Comment: @DirkBruere Yes. I think I get that much. It integrates the current coming in, holding the (-) input as a virtual ground.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to be more specific, with a schematic of the proposed protection, including source and load impedances. In the absence of that, here's a start.

Any series elements (if resistive) will add Johnson noise.

Any parallel elements (such as reverse biased diodes) will add shot noise current in relation to their reverse leakage current : assuming it's a voltage amplifier, you can translate that to a voltage developed across source and load impedances in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

The LTC1150 is rated at 1.8µV P-P (0.1Hz to 10Hz)

1/f noise is thermionic and related to conduction current and higher temperatures in semiconductors.

Is this noise you are asking about within this bandwidth or above?
If above then you need to consider GBW and inbalance of signal loop and use CM choke.